# Fedora on Bootable USB won't update

Tags: fedora

I installed Fedora Workstation 34 on a USB and I can't update anything.

It says something like: "Unable to update: [...] needs 'XXX' mb more space on the /filesystem ".

It is a brand new install on a 64gb usb stick. I used Fedora Media Writer run the installation.

Since I'll be travelling more for the next weeks, I wanted to use it as my "PC", install Discord, Notion, Trello and stuff so won't have to log in on a new machine every time.

Can it be done through the Fedora OS on a Bootable USB?

Comment: How do you mean "I installed ..."? Did you copy a "Live" ISO image to the USB? If so, the filesystem on the ISO image is (mostly) non-mutable. You will have to do a full install, partitioning the USB drive with sufficient partition sizes.

Comment: As I said, I used the Fedora Media Writer. Is it necessary to partition the pendrive to properly install the OS? Or can I just run boot through the image I already have and properly install it on a empty pendrive?

Comment: To the first statement: No, That does not "install" the OS, it simply copies an already ISO-installed OS, exactly as presented in the ISO image--so you did not "install" it, only copied it. To the question: Yes, you will have to actually partition the USB stick _and_ actually _install_ the OS using the OSes installation procedure.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any proper tutorial for that using MacOS or Ubuntu? I can only find it using Rufus on Windows (not an option here).

Comment: Let's step back a moment and examine what your end goal is. You want to create a "portable PC" on a USB stick, so you can plug it in to any computer and boot it off the USB, work with it as if it was your own home computer, and so on, correct?

Comment: That's correct, sir. I want to have all my apps all installed and logged in wherever I go, without having to carry a laptop as an extra weight in my backpack. (The PC there where I'll regularly travel to is a very good one. Its performance alone won't be an issue.)

Comment: Okay. Edit to update your question and topic to indicate that--many users here will not dig through the comments here to see if they are interested in, or know a working answer to your issue. As for how to install Fedora to a USB drive, I am not certain. But I am making a guess that it is not very different than any other Linux-based distro. Try searching the web for "installing linux to usb drive".

Answer (score 2):

That’s just the Fedora LiveCD image, it is not really intended for updating/installing.  If you want to install Fedora on a usb disk, you need to boot that image and use the installer to deploy Fedora on another storage device.

It’s possible to add and update software on the livecd image, you’ll need to use the [livecd-iso-to-disk](https://github.com/livecd-tools/livecd-tools/blob/main/docs/livecd-iso-to-disk.pod) command to write an image with a certain amount of overlay space.  Any space you configure will be used for changes to the root filesystem.  Deleting files won’t reclaim space.